# Bind scoping javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, scoping

I'm trying to figure out scoping of using bind. I'm confused about the output of `boundF1`. What is going on here?

```
// console.log(x) ReferenceError: x is not defined

// setting this.x - this here is global or window
this.x = 5;
console.log(x) // 5

function f1() {
  console.log(x); // 5
  console.log(this.x); // 5
}

// Lexically bound this to window 
f2 = () => {
  console.log(x); // 5
  console.log(this.x); // 5
}

f1()
f2()

boundF1 = f1.bind({x:1});
boundF2 = f2.bind({x:1});


boundF1() // 5 1 Why is this not 1, 1. How is x resolved here? Does it check local vars, then global vars. Would it ever use this? What is the scoping rule?

boundF2() // 5 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference a standalone variable, like `console.log(x)`, the interpreter will try to find a standalone variable with that same name somewhere in the outer scope. Here, the outer scope eventually gets to the global scope, and so `console.log(x)` resolves to `console.log(window.x)`.

Properties of `this` do *not* get added to a function's variable environment; to reference properties of `this`, you have to do so explicitly, eg:

```
console.log(this.x);
```

Not that you should ever use it, but there is `with`, which lets you reference properties of an object as if they were standalone variables (which sounds like what you were *thinking* would happen automatically), but it's highly not recommended (and forbidden in strict mode).

```js
this.x = 5;

function f1() {
  with (this) {
    console.log(x); // 5
    console.log(this.x); // 5
  }
}

boundF1 = f1.bind({x:1});


boundF1()
```

Comment: This is my first time coming across with. That's really cool. Why is it not recommended?

Comment: @patrick_corrigan It can make code a *lot* slower than it would be otherwise, and also makes the code a lot more confusing to read. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with and https://2ality.com/2011/06/with-statement.html . I was only referencing it because it seemed like you were assuming `with(this)` would happen automatically

Comment: @CertainPerformance, Yes that is what I was assuming. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Cause `x` will always look up the variable *in the scope*. It has nothing todo with `this` (the *context*). When you call `.bind`, you only set the value of `this` inside of a function.

Comment: Thank you. Is this the lexical scope? Why is it that when I call f1() I get 5 5, is that because this and the scope are the same in this case?

Comment: Yes, kind of. If you call f1(), `x` will be looked up in the local function scope, then in the global scope. `this` will refer to the global scope. Add `let x = 10;` inside of the function to change that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

in f2, because it's an unbindable arrow function, `x` and `this.x` both refer to `window.x`.

In f1, `x` will first try to find any locally scoped variable x and if it can't, will search for an `x` in the global scope. But because it's bound, `this` no longer refers to `window` but to the object you bound it to, so `this.x` is the x-value of the object you bound it to.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `f1()` in the first print statement you are printing `x` not `this.x`, so when you bind it with the object `{x:1}` with the `Function.prototype.bind()` you are passing the `this` as `{x:1}` object.
But in the function you are reading the value of `x` from the global scope not from the `this` context you have bound to.

So when you execute the function `f1` and printing `x` it is looking for the `x` in local scope first, since it didn't find any it will look up in the parent scope which is the global scope in this case.

If there were no `x` declared in the global scope you would have gotten a `ReferenceError`:

```js
function f1() {
  console.log(this.x); // 1
  console.log(x); // ReferenceError as x is not declared in any scope
}
f1.bind({x:1})();
```

The scope rules are explained in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope):

> Scopes can also be layered in a hierarchy, so that child scopes have
>   access to parent scopes, but not vice versa.